# It is possible to make NavigationView title clickable in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to add action on tap to `NavigationView` title. Is it possible in SwiftUI?

Comment: As you can padding the NavigationView, its very easy to fake any `NavigationView title` on the top of the screen

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the `.inline` title display mode, you can use the new `toolbar` API introduced in iOS 14 to overwrite the title displayed in the navigation bar.

See below a simple example, where tapping the title is incrementing the counter:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Main content")
                Text("\(counter)")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Press here")
                        .bold()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            counter += 1
                        }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed .bold() translates to `.semibold` apparently?